# Text inside badge

Tags: android, autocompletetextview, badge

In my application i have a `AutoCompleteTextView` within which the user inserts a series of tags to categorize an element. I would like to make sure that every time the user inserts a tag and makes a space, the tag he inserted was put inside a badge like these:

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Those are called Chips https://github.com/klinker41/android-chips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , First of all these text inside badge as you said is known as **Chips** , and you can acheive this by MaterialChipLayout

https://github.com/pchmn/MaterialChipsInput

follow this after adding this into your build , it will solve your problem.